# Python: saving large web page to file

Tags: python, file, urllib2

Let me start off by saying, I'm not new to programming but am very new to python.

I've written a program using urllib2 that requests a web page that I would then like to save to a file.  The web page is about 300KB, which doesn't strike me as particularly large but seems to be enough to give me trouble, so I'm calling it 'large'.
I'm using a simple call to copy directly from the object returned from `urlopen` into the file:

`file.write(webpage.read())`

but it will just sit for minutes, trying to write into the file and I eventually receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "program.py", line 43, in main
    f.write(webpage.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 351, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(rbufsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 541, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 592, in _read_chunked
    value.append(self._safe_read(amt))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 649, in _safe_read
    raise IncompleteRead(''.join(s), amt)
httplib.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(6384 bytes read, 1808 more expected)
```

I don't know why this should give the program so much grief?

---

### EDIT  |

here is how I'm retrieving the page

```
jar = cookielib.CookieJar()

cookie_processor = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar);

opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie_processor)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

requ_login = urllib2.Request(LOGIN_PAGE,
                             data = urllib.urlencode( { 'destination' : "", 'username' : USERNAME, 'password' :  PASSWORD } ))

requ_page = urllib2.Request(WEBPAGE)    
try:
    #login
    urllib2.urlopen(requ_login)

    #get desired page
    portfolio = urllib2.urlopen(requ_page)
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    print e.code, ": ", e.reason
```

Comment: Can you show how you are opening the page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670257/httplib-incomplete-read might be related.

Comment: A couple of things to isolate...If you just read into an array, I assume you have the same problem without doing any file writing.  Also, what if you specify a max size to the read call, like read(500000)?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://bobrochel.blogspot.com/2010/11/bad-servers-chunked-encoding-and.html

Comment: I get the same result from reading into an array, I also tried adding a max size to read, still no.  I edited the orginal question to include the code I'm using to get the page.

Comment: I used the shutil.copyfileobj as suggested below, and it seems to be working now.  Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: *I used the shutil.copyfileobj as suggested below, and it seems to be working now. Any idea why this is the case?* I'm curious as well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a handy [fileobject copier function](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) provided by `shutil` module. It worked on my machine :)

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> import shutil
>>> remote_fo = urllib2.urlopen('http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html')
>>> with open('bigfile', 'wb') as local_fo:
...     shutil.copyfileobj(remote_fo, local_fo)
... 
>>>
```

**UPDATE:** You may want to pass the 3rd argument to `copyfileobj` that controls the size of internal buffer used to transfer bytes.

**UPDATE2:** There's nothing fancy about `shutil.copyfileobj.` It simply reads a chunk of bytes from source file object and writes it the destination file object repeatedly until there's nothing more to read. Here's the actual source code of it that I grabbed from inside Python standard library:

```
def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024):
    """copy data from file-like object fsrc to file-like object fdst"""
    while 1:
        buf = fsrc.read(length)
        if not buf:
            break
        fdst.write(buf)
```

Comment: Thank you, I used did this and it seems to be working now.  Do you have an idea of what copyfileobj does differently that makes it work better?

Comment: Hi @JustinSmith, see my answer again, I've updated it with more info. `copyfileobj` doesn't do anything especially profound. Just copies bytes to the destination file one chunk at a time.

Comment: This still doesn't explain what's wrong with the original code.

Comment: The real problem actually turned out to be that the request was timing out because of the large file size. I increased the timeout and everything worked after that

Comment: I used this approach for [copying a remote binary file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28306886/1497596). (For example, an image file.)