# How do I save the content of a url to a .txt file?

Tags: python, html, url

The code failed.

Could anyone help?

I search in stack overflow, and tried some methods, but I can't seem to find any that work.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

link = "https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=IKQkjWmqQv8&is_popout=1"

f = urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
print (myfile)
output_file = open('1.txt','w')
output_file.write(myfile)
output_file.close()
```

Comment: Try `'wb'` for your file mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: saving large web page to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220669/python-saving-large-web-page-to-file)

Comment: Thank you. It works. However the content of the website cannot be loaded. It said the browser version does not support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

link = "https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=IKQkjWmqQv8&is_popout=1"

f = urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
print (myfile)
output_file = open('1.txt','wb')
output_file.write(myfile)
output_file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. However the content of the website cannot be loaded. It said the browser version does not support

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a bytes back from your `read()`, you could just write this to your file in binary mode by adding a `b` as follows:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

link = "https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=IKQkjWmqQv8&is_popout=1"

f = urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
print (myfile)

with open('output.html','wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(myfile)
```

Note: Using `with` is the preferred method for dealing with files. It will automatically close your file for you afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. It works. However the content of the website cannot be loaded. It said the browser version does not support.

Comment: I suggest you rename the output file to `output.html` and try loading that into you browser.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are true, but you can decode bytes to string. To do that, just modify these 2 lines:

```
...
output_file = open('1.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8")
output_file.write(myfile.decode("utf8"))
...
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. However the content of the website cannot be loaded. It said the browser version does not support