# download image from url using python urllib but receiving HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: image, python-3.x, url, download, urllib

I want to download image file from a url using python module "urllib.request", which works for some website (e.g. mangastream.com), but does not work for another (mangadoom.co) receiving error "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden". What could be the problem for the latter case and how to fix it?

I am using python3.4 on OSX.

```
import urllib.request

# does not work
img_url = 'http://mangadoom.co/wp-content/manga/5170/886/005.png'
img_filename = 'my_img.png'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url, img_filename)
```

At the end of error message it said:

```
... 
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

However, it works for another website

```
# work
img_url = 'http://img.mangastream.com/cdn/manga/51/3140/006.png'
img_filename = 'my_img.png'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url, img_filename)
```

I have tried the solutions from the post below, but none of them works on mangadoom.co.

[Downloading a picture via urllib and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python)

[How do I copy a remote image in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394721/how-do-i-copy-a-remote-image-in-python)

The solution here also does not fit because my case is to download image.
[urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden)

Non-python solution is also welcome. Your suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden)

Comment: The site restricts downloading so you get 403 Error in response from the site.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This website is blocking the user-agent used by urllib, so you need to change it in your request. Unfortunately I don't think `urlretrieve` supports this directly.

I advise for the use of the beautiful `requests` library, the code becomes (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)) :

```
import requests
import shutil

r = requests.get('http://mangadoom.co/wp-content/manga/5170/886/005.png', stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open("img.png", 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Note that it seems this website does not forbide `requests` user-agent. But if need to be modified it is easy :

```
r = requests.get('http://mangadoom.co/wp-content/manga/5170/886/005.png',
                 stream=True, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

Also relevant : [changing user-agent in urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226781/changing-user-agent-in-python-3-for-urrlib-urlopen)

Answer (score 26):

You can build an opener. Here's the example:

```
import urllib.request

opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

url=''
local=''
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,local)
```

By the way, the following codes are the same:

(none-opener)

```
req=urllib.request.Request(url,data,hdr)   
html=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

(opener builded)

```
html=operate.open(url,data,timeout)
```

However, we are not able to add header when we use:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve()
```

So in this case, we have to build an opener.

Answer (score 10):

I try wget with the url in terminal and it works:

```
wget -O out_005.png  http://mangadoom.co/wp-content/manga/5170/886/005.png
```

so my way around is to use the script below, and it works too.

```
import os
out_image = 'out_005.png'
url = 'http://mangadoom.co/wp-content/manga/5170/886/005.png'
os.system("wget -O {0} {1}".format(out_image, url))
```