# urlretrieve not working for this site

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to download an image, however it does seem to work. Is it being blocked by ddos protection?

Here is the code:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://archive.is/Xx9t3/scr.png", "test.png")
```

Basically download that image as "test.png." I'm using python3 hence the urllib.request before urlretrieve.

```
import urllib.request
```

Have that as well.

Any way I can download the image? thanks!

Comment: You might have more luck with an answer if you post more information, like what error you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons that I cannot even imagine, the server requires a well known user agent. So you must pretend to use for example firefox and it will accept to send the image:

```
# first build a request object
req = urllib.request.Request("http://archive.is/Xx9t3/scr.png",
        headers = {
           'User-agent':
              'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0'})

#then use it
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
with open("test.png","wb") as fd:
    fd.write(resp.read())
```

Rather stupid, but when a server admin goes mad, just be as stupid as he is...

Comment: thanks worked! Also weird but using write() worked without headers as well using: f.write(requests.get("http://archive.is/Xx9t3/scr.png").content)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org), basically *the way* you are trying to get the image is forbidden, check this:

```
import requests
import shutil

r = requests.get('http://archive.is/Xx9t3/scr.png', stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open("test.png", 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

*This snippet was adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692009/download-image-from-url-using-python-urllib-but-receiving-http-error-403-forbid)*

The **magic** behind this is how the resource is retrieved, with `requests` that part is the `stream=True` line. Some servers are more restricted with this methods to pull some resources like media.